# How to fix auto activating checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.checkbox1').attr('checked') == true) {
   $(".worddoc").animate({opacity:1},700);
  }
 })
```

```css
.checkbox1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.checkbox1:not(checked) + label {
  padding-right: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox1:not(checked) + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 71%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox1:not(checked) + label:not(checked):before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 73%;
  top: -2px;
  z-index: 998;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox1:checked + label:after {
  background: #9FD468;
}

.checkbox1:checked + label:before {
  left: 82%;
}

.label1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: OpenSansRegular;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.worddoc {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" autocomplete="off"/>
  <label for="checkbox1" class="label1">jQuery</label>
<div class="worddoc"></div>
```

Hey guys. I want my 1 element appears when checkbox is active, but it gets active right away after loading DOM on website. autocomplete="off" attribute doesn't solve the problem. HELP! I rely on you, guys!

Comment: Can you provide the css instead of the scss, please? Also, where is the .worddoc element?

Comment: Sure. And worddoc element is not so important but i have put it in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkbox1').click(function () {
        if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(".worddoc").animate({opacity:1,right:0},700);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably i will need to hide this element by turning that checkbox off. So i need to show the element only depending on checkbox status

Comment: You can use removeAttr to remove attribute or prop to uncheck it

Comment: It's really very weird but it doesn't work despite of this logical code. Probably some problem is lurking behind all. I need to check my code again